# How to set popover target dynamically with ReactStrap

Tags: reactjs, popover, reactstrap

I'm searching for a method to set popover target dynamically with ReactStrap
Using React version 17, not interested in jquery solutions, thanks for your help.

```
<Button id=popover1 type="button" className="btn-evenement">
  Name Button
</Button>
<Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={popoverOpen} target=popover1 toggle={toggle} trigger="focus" >
```

The above code will work with no problems, but by adding `id={newId}` and `target={newId}`:

```
<Button id={newId} type="button" className="btn-evenement">
  Name Button            
</Button>
<Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={popoverOpen} target={newId} toggle={toggle} trigger="focus" >
```

There will be an error:

```
TypeError: target.removeEventListener is not a function
(anonymous function)

D:/******/node_modules/reactstrap/es/TooltipPopoverWrapper.js:260
257 | 
258 | _proto.removeEventOnTargets = function removeEventOnTargets(type, handler, isBubble) {
259 |   this._targets.forEach(function (target) {
260 |     target.removeEventListener(type, handler, isBubble);
```